# How to include external script into <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

Inside my JS function I need to add this:

```
< script src=https://xxxx.com/c3.js type="text/javascript" async defer>< /script>
```

How to edit the code the right way?

```
<script>
function affilate() {                   
        var ab_instance = "xxx.com";
        var ab_kampan = 3;
        var ab_cena = 1; 
        var ab_id_transakce = document.getElementById("email").value;
              
    <script src=https://xxxx.com/c3.js type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
                                    
    console.log(ab_id_transakce);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: What does _"Inside my JS function I need to add this"_ mean?

Comment: May I ask why do you need to add script inside your js and not in your HTML? I guess, you should add the script to your HTML body.

Comment: Append a script tag with the needed attributes to `<head>`. Check also [Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: Its conversion code what have two parts. first is < script>                 
        var ab_instance = "xxx.com"; .....> and second is <script>src=https://xxxx.com/c3.js......</script> but i need both in one function

Comment: and function affilate() is onclick function in form. So i need count conversion only when someone click on submit button. And there should be code with variables and then code what send this variables on third part server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to add a script tag to the DOM. It seems that you are trying to add the HTML script tag in the Javascript function, which will not work. What you can try is:

1. Add the script tag directly in the HTML like this:

```html
<script src=https://xxxx.com/c3.js type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
<script>
function affilate() {                   
    var ab_instance = "xxx.com";
    var ab_kampan = 3;
    var ab_cena = 1; 
    var ab_id_transakce = document.getElementById("email").value;                             
    console.log(ab_id_transakce);
}
 </script>
```

2. Add the script tag dynamically

```
<script>
    function affilate() {
        var ab_instance = "xxx.com";
        var ab_kampan = 3;
        var ab_cena = 1;
        var ab_id_transakce = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(ab_id_transakce);

        var script_tag = document.createElement("script");
        script_tag.src = "https://xxxx.com/c3.js";
        script_tag.type = "text/javascript";
        script_tag.async = true;
        script_tag.defer = true;

        // in case you want to add the script tag to the <head>
        document.head.appendChild(script_tag);

        // in case you want to add the script tag to the <body>
        document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
    }
</script>
```